If someone buys a ticket for me, can they check if I am actually on the flight?
Before anyone says anything, no I am not victim of a scam.
I am just curious, if someone buys a ticket for me, can they check if I am actually on the flight? Could they find out, even if they didn't pay for my ticket but for example know some details about me? Is this considered confidential information or is it given out relatively easily?
For example: can a tour operator check if his clients have boarded the plane they paid for. Can a tour operator (not airline) easily find out someone used the hidden city trick (as another example)?
I am talking about EU.

If you do not take a flight, the actual fare is lost, but taxes and airport/security fees are refunded to the payment method used. This takes a few days, though. The ticket status on CheckMyTrip (requires booking reference and last name) will likely update quicker.

@SimonRichter I missed my flight and to my knowledge received nothing back from ryanair.

@SimonRichter Which airlines do this? Maybe this is an American thing? Here in Europe I have never heard of an automatic chargeback of any part of the ticket price - you sometimes get (parts of) your fees back on request, but it's far from guaranteed.

@SimonRichter That may be very much dependent on where the flight is (not) taken and the resulting laws. I've missed a couple flights in my time, lost all the money, and nothing was ever refunded. In the most recent time (now maybe 10 years ago, in Asia) I found I could request a refund of those fees, but it was not automatic. Didn't bother.

Define "confidential". If you have certain details (e.g.: booking reference and the traveler's name, or sometimes just the surname) it can be easily accessible online. If you don't and you want to find out that may be more difficult. However, a legitimate travel agent booking reservations for the group may have a significantly different level of access to that reservation than a random person trying to stalk someone.

Can a tour operator (not airline) easily find out someone used the hidden city trick (as another example)?

I can't imagine why they'd care about the hidden city trick, but they most definitely care to know if someone in their group has missed their planned flight. Should the rest of the group wait? Should that person be assisted with additional bookings? That's literally their job to know.

People in the comments insisted on legal proofs and undeniable examples for this hypothetical question. One example is calling the airline and asking, which is exactly what I did when I needed to recall isome nformation for a missing mileage request. The airlines keep track of the actual manifest (check out aviation@SE to ask what that is) and provided the answer to me after some trivial identity verification that anyone with my reservation details could pass.
The question is asking whether it's possible to find out - it definitely is.

"That's literally their job to know." Just to confirm, can they know whether their clients boarded or not?

@FranckDernoncourt can? For sure. They have the booking reference and they have the name, even I can look that up, don't need to be a travel agent for that. Do they have any system automating that knowledge? probably, don't know.

How do you check whether the passenger boarded the plane?

@FranckDernoncourt I was able to see other people's boarding passes when I needed with that information. I've never had a case where someone would check in and then not board, but I've had cases when seats were changed or luggage checked at the gate and these were correctly reflected.

@FranckDernoncourt: by asking the airline: the scenario seems a group ticket, and it is task of both side to communicate (to get good deal in future). Also often there are people delayed or that cancelled last minute so sharing information is beneficial on both sides. -- Note: that was for groups: I'm less sure on one off booking by travel agency.

How can I look up online if I myself have boarded my plane? Never seen this option. Maybe if you call, haven't tried.

@littleadv I think you are right, boarding passes are ofc available after online checkin. But technically its not info on boarding, you could check in online and then miss your flight for example.

I don't know if a boarding pass remains valid if you check in but not board. I would imagine it wouldn't be. But I've never been in this situation nor anyone of whom I've been arranging travel for. I know you can check if you boarded the flight if you contact the airline. I had to call once to ask what seat I was seating on for a missing mileage request.

@littleadv but the seat is assigned on checkin not on boarding

@user1721135 the manifest includes only the people boarded, they knew I actually flew. Not entirely sure what you're trying to get to here.

@littleadv what is the manifest?

I don’t think this answers the question at all. Obviously it’s easy to check ticket information as the purchaser, regardless of the beneficiary. But I have never seen a system in which even I myself as the ticket holder could have determine if I actually took the flight (other than realizing I did get to the destination). Most I got was whether I did check in. An answer should reflect on if there’s any way to obtain such info as the purchaser.

@Neinstein but that wasn't the question. The question was whether it's possible - and it is, for example: I called the airline when I needed this information for the missing mileage request and they had it. It wasn't very hard to get that either, all I need was to say some bits of personal info that anyone with reservation details would have.

@user1721135 you might want to take that to the aviation@SE.

it would be off-topic there.

@user1721135 re "How can I look up online if I myself have boarded my plane": IME: the airlines I fly with tend to allow me to request a refund on just the taxes or rebook when I miss/skip a flight, showing a slightly different UI on the manage your booking page (which can be often accessed with PNR and last name alone).


I am just curious, if someone buys a ticket for me, can they check if I am actually on the flight? Could they find out, even if they didn't pay for my ticket but for example know some details about me? Is this considered confidential information or is it given out relatively easily?

In theory, the information about a reservation is private.
In practice the bar to access (most of) the details is very, very, low. On most airlines, one can access a reservation with only a reservation number (PNR or e-ticket) and one or two details about the reservation (name of passenger or departure airport are most common).
I strongly discourage posting photos of one's boarding pass or reservation on social medias for this very reason.

For example: can a tour operator check if his clients have boarded the plane they paid for. Can a tour operator (not airline) easily find out someone used the hidden city trick (as another example)? I am talking about EU.

A tour operator is a completely different scenario from a "random" person: by using their service, the customer has explicitly delegated management of their travel(s).
Tour operators generally do not make a reservation per customer. They'll reserve N seats in advance -- for the planned group size -- then carve out subsets of those seats for the groups of customers who buy the tour.
As the operator, they retain full control over the reservation. In particular, they can change the flights, add/remove services, shuffle seats around, etc...
They are also trusted to edit very confidential details (PII): phone numbers, e-mail addresses, addresses of residence, addresses of stay, ID cards, passport cards, visas, etc... One of the reason to choose a tour operator, after all, is to let them handle all those pesky details.
And in order to do so, they use airline-provided professional applications, which give them a complete overview of everything in the reservation they manage. In theory, they can therefore see whether one of their customer boarded.
They may not have (much) in the way of automation, but:

A human could definitely check, manually.
An airline could notify them a customer did not board.

I mean, a tour operator leaving a customer stranded in a foreign land would get quite bad press, they have an interest in double-checking, though they may not to cut costs.

The tour operators may also face issues if the people they brought into the country overstay or seek asylum (depends on country and agreements ofc). If this happens too frequently this may affect their status as a recognized tour operator with that country, due to suspicions of human trafficking (getting someone from point A to B thru fraud, even if said person is willingly opting into this, does often qualify as human trafficking, I like this example).

@ave having information on who is on what flight changes noting for the tour operator in this instance. It does not help him knowing people skipped the flight.

Slightly different answer: this will depend a lot on the way the ticket was booked and the contracts between the airline, the passenger and the 3rd party.
On many airlines (but not all) it's easy enough to look up a booking if you have the PNR and the last name. In most cases you can tell whether the passenger has checked in but not if they have actually boarded. This requires access to the flight manifest which most airlines won't give out to random people.
I'm sure that most professional travel arranger have both the legal framework and the infrastructure in place to assess this information but without a proper authorization the airline is unlikely to give this data when you call them up.
I've privately booked plenty of tickets for friends and family, but I don't think I was able to asses their boarding status. In fact, one of my sons actually boarded the wrong flight once by accident and there was no notification or update to me as the purchaser of the ticket.

At the time, was your son making flying as an unaccompanied minor (paid service with some airlines)?

Why would a travel agent have any more access? Its not like the travel agent needs to know if people really took the flight or not. Why would he need this information?

@Brain: No. I think we was still a minor but used to flying alone without any added service.

@user1721135: depends on the type travel agent. If you organize tours for large groups with little travel experience, you really need to know if everyone has boarded the plane of if you need to start hunting stragglers and or rescue people who were left behind.

@Hilmar you mean the thing where they go around the airport looking for people who didn’t board? Isn’t that usually done by either airline or airport personnel.

@user1721135: Airport personnel doesn't care. They may make an announcement but that's where it ends. Airlines may or may not care. Typically they only start looking for real if they have to unload checked  bags. There are professional tour operators that have boots in the airport to herd and look for people. This quite common for example at Hadj time when you see very large groups of pilgrims in matching outfits and suitcases at some airports.
